# PhoneGap - InAppPurchase plugin - window.storekit is undefined

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I´m having a problem using the plugin below to manage in-app purchases http://fovea.cc/blog/index.php/3-steps-tutorial-for-phonegap-2x-in-app-purchase-on-ios/

i think i have installed it correctly. but sometimes it seem to be work fine but sometimes it window.storekit object is undefined

It must be that the object is not being created because the code is not executed? As far as i know, that plugin available for JS is created in the file cordova_plugins.js

Did anyone has the same problem before? I've been trying different things  and i can´t find the problem!

Comment: "but sometimes it seem to be work fine but sometimes it window.storekit object is undefined" So sometimes every single aspect of the plugin works and sometimes not? You need to be more specific here. Are you sure you are using the [**j3ko IAP Plugin**](https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS)? Because it is an **iOS** Plugin and you put **Android** in the tags. Also, which version of Cordova/Phonegap are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it sometimes work, sometimes don't work, it's most probably because you're accessing the `window.storekit` object before the `deviceready` event was triggered by PhoneGap.

You need to do `document.addEventListener("deviceready", yourCallbackFunction, false);` Only then you can access plugins from your callback function.

See [PhoneGap's documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) for more details about the `deviceready` event).